# Why doesn't this code work as as fast as I need it to?

Tags: c++, double

I was able to get this to run in 1.65 secs but I have a feeling that it could be faster. Doubles maybe?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int n) {
    if(n%2 == 0 && n!=2) return false;
    for(int i=3; i<n/2; i++) {
        if(n%i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int num, i; 
    i=1000000007;
    num = 1000000008;
    for(;i<num; i++) {
        if(isPrime(i)) cout << i << endl;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how the 'equivalent code in C' is any different outside of the way output is done. Some information is missing there.

Comment: In your for loop `i` doesn't change is always `3`.

Comment: @chris debugging is going to take a whole lot of time since `i=1000000007;` :)

Comment: @40two `break if` helps in situations where looping is involved.

Comment: @40two, It's not too hard to step through code and notice `i` in the function never changes.

Comment: @chris I was joking dude :)

Comment: @40two, I must be drunk. Even though I don't drink.

Comment: This was my 5th or 6th time writing a program like this but the increment bit slipped through the cracks this time... glad it did as I have stumbled upon optimization and <code>break if</code> for it. BTW, I'll use a debugger as I advance. For now, interacting with humans has its advantages for me as student and this site as a place for others to learn. @chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no increment in the for loop in "isPrime". You have:

```
for(int i=3; i<n/2;)
```

You should have:

```
for(int i=3; i<n/2; i++)
```

Edit: since a commenter brought up optimizations, there are two things you can do to easily and greatly reduce the number of operations for large values of n.

The first is, as commented, to increment i by 2 (I am leaving my answer as is, since the point of the question was "why doesn't the code work" and not "how do I optimize the code," and it's easier for novice programmers to see the fix in its simplest form) since you already know you've eliminated all even numbers from the prior conditional.

The second is to only check up to the square root of n and not n divided by 2. The reason is as follows: if n is not prime, then there are two numbers greater than 1 and less than n that satisfy the condition

```
n = x * y
```

If both x and y are greater than the square root of n, then `x * y` is greater than n. Thus, if you haven't found any factors by time you iterate past the square root of n, n is prime.

Comment: It can be, but doesn't have to be in order to function. i+=2 is more efficient, but he can stop much earlier than i < n/2 as well, if you want to get into prime related optimizations.

Comment: You have been quite helpful. I'm a beginner as you can see.

Comment: Everybody was a beginner once :) Just keep writing code and thinking about why it works or why it doesn't work :)

Comment: Very insightful. The point of this program for me is to compare the speeds of various languages on various platforms. Is it safe to say that this optimization (more efficiency and effectiveness) equals faster?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Stopping at sqrt(n) (you'll need to cast to a double and cast back to int if using math.h) and incrementing by 2 instead of 1 is definitely faster and still correct, but in order for the comparison to be valid against other languages, you should effect this change in all languages. I'd also like to add that when comparing the performance of languages, features beyond basic iteration and arithmetic should be tested -- so, consider writing additional tests for things like string comparison, standard library functions, sorting algorithms, memory management, etc.